# Controlling Google-Maps for Android Caching

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

I have an map-enabled app and chances are high that there is sometimes no network in the location the user wants to use it. Is there any way to get control over the offline caching functionality of google-maps - so I can do a caching in beforehand while the user still has network?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get control over the offline caching functionality of google-maps - so I can do a caching in beforehand while the user still has network?

No, sorry. There is very little caching with the Google Maps add-on for Android in the first place, and none of that is controllable by SDK applications.

Comment: thanks for your answer - I upvoted but I do not want to accept as I hope for a better answer after the recent announcements of google regarding offline and google maps ;-)

Comment: @ligi: We all hope. OTOH, there have been many upgrades to the Google Maps app, none of which have been propagated to the Google Maps SDK add-on.